# DeploymentCatalog security error

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mef

I'm trying to use the DeploymentCatalog to load my service implementations by MEF. I have the implementation in a single xap. when I use the following code to download it , every thing is ok :

var catalog = new DeploymentCatalog("MyXap.xap");

catalog.DownloadAsync();

I put my xap on a remote server , say on http://ip:90/Myxap.xap, when I write the same code but with the uri , it throws a deployment exception:

var catalog = new DeploymentCatalog(new Uri("http://ip:90/MyXap.xap",UriKind.Absolute));catalog.DownloadAsync();

Any help .

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the XAP you are trying to download is hosted at a different domain (or different port, I think) than your Silverlight App is, you will need a [cross domain policy file](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx) on the site that hosts your XAP to allow your Silverlight App to access it.

If that's not the problem, you'll need to provide more information.  Edit your question to include the full text of the deployment exception you get.

Comment: Thank you very much . I added the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the root directory where is my xaps, and its working now.